# Почему logrotate ругается на права /var/log/?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, права

Утилита [logrotate](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate) ругается на то, что у `/var/log` небезопасные права (permissions):

```
root@home:~# logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/foo
```

> error: skipping "/var/log/foo.log" because parent directory has insecure permissions (It's world writable or writable by group which is not "root") Set "su" directive in config file to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.

```
root@home:/var/log# ls -hal foo.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 161K Jan 25 17:16 foo.log

root@home:/var/log# ls -ld
drwxrwxr-x 9 root syslog 4.0K Jan 25 16:26 .
```

Похоже, права действительно слишком свободные. Вопрос: насколько нужно их ограничить? Какие права должны быть у этой директории? Нужно ли ограничивать права всех вложенных директорий?

Было бы здорово получить объяснение, а не только три числа для chmod. :)

---

По поводу предлагаемого в сообщении решения.

В файле `/etc/logrotate.conf` уже есть такие строки:

```
# use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root syslog
```

В `/etc/logrotate.d/foo` директива `su` не переопределяется.

Comment: А что за группа syslog ? Обычно syslog под рутом работает и спец-права ему не нужны. А если каким то службам надо писать логи не через syslog, а самим, то я предпочитаю завести внутри /var/log для них отдельный каталог на который поставить права для них лично (apache, mail, mysql). а на сам /var/log root.root 755

Comment: @Mike: не знаю, не я создавал. Дело в том, что syslog сейчас как-то работает и я не хочу это сломать. Но при этом нужно добавить ещё логи в ротацию, а это вызывает ошибки.

Comment: @Mike: кстати, зачем последнее `5`? Разве для others нужен вообще хоть какой-то доступ?

Comment: В принципе не нужен. но дистрибутивы почему то предпочитают делать так. Достаточно было бы 'x' всем дать, что бы какой нибудь mysql свободно прошел сквозь /var/log в свой подкаталог /var/log/mysql. Если будет 750 - то он не пройдет. А --x редко кто и на что ставит, проще не задумываясь особо дать r-x :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

добавьте в конфигурационный файл `/etc/logrotate.conf` требующуюся директиву:

```
su root syslog
```

---

а менять права/принадлежность файлов и каталогов в `/var/log` обычно не сто́ит.

---

дополнительная информация: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/logrotate/+bug/1278193

---

**обновление в связи со всплывшей информацией**

по поводу команды:

```
$ sudo logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/foo
```

1. для тестирования изменений, вносимых в конфигурацию, сто́ит запускать программу `logrotate` с опцией `-d` (debug, отладка, реальных изменений произведено не будет).
2. в качестве параметра сто́ит указывать конфигурационный файл программы (`/etc/logrotate.conf`), а не «кусочек» конфигурации из файла, находящегося в каталоге `/etc/logrotate.d/`. эти «кусочки» и так будут подключены в то место конфигурационного файла, где написана директива `include /etc/logrotate.d`.
3. ошибка про «неправильные» права при выполении **этой** команды связана с тем, что по умолчанию программа `logrotate` использует не ту связку пользователь-группа, которая задана в конфигурационном файле (в дистрибутивах *ubuntu* последних версий — это `root:syslog`; директива: `su root syslog`), а, скорее всего, связку `root:root`, которая, естественно, не соответствует актуальной принадлежности каталога `/var/log`. но конфигурационный файл `/etc/logrotate.conf` не интерпретируется при запуске (указан совсем другой файл — `/etc/logrotate.d/foo`), вот программа и сообщает об ошибке.

Comment: Тут пишут, что `/var/log` нужно беречь, как кощееву иглу. Ошибаются? [Why not permit read access for all in /var/log?](http://askubuntu.com/a/123143)

Comment: *Тут пишут* — пишут фактически то же самое, что и в моём ответе: не стоит менять права на файлы/каталоги в `/var/log`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34824/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-alexander-barakin).

Comment: Я понимаю, что это немного старая тема, но у меня на `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS` логи kern и ufw не обрабатываются - файлы логов просто пучит, когда пытаешься отладить ufw. `su root syslog` не помогает. Помогает `su root adm`. `groups user` возвращает `adm`, но не `syslog`. Насколько все секурно, и куда копать, чтобы узнать, какие настройки правильные?

Comment: @oshliaer, если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы

Answer (score -1):

Необходимо просто снять излишнии права с папки и ругаться перестанет

```
 ls -ld
```

**drwxr-xr-x** 2 root root 4096 Jun 23 08:12 .